Is more than 20 hours per week too much workload to students?
I am checking my course evaluation for the last course I taught. Among all the statistics, one thing surprised me a bit is that there are about 50% of students who did the evaluation reported that they had worked 20-28 hours per week on my course. The university in general suggests that a course like mine should take students 20 about 20 hours, including lecture time (5 hours), which means half of their workload.
If the students are not exaggerating, I feel maybe I have packed a bit too much information into the course. (The average grades are quite good actually. About 1/3 of the students got an A.)
Should I perhaps reduce a bit of the material given this information?

Do they have other classes? If the course is not the main content of the semester, spending more than 20 hours a week on a single course seems excessive.

It should be about half of their total workload.

Then it seems to me that if half your students are spending a little more than 20 hours and half are spending a little less, you have the workload right

@Significance This is true. Although I feel a bit surprised that they would actually spent that much time.

It's worth mentioning that students spend more time on courses they enjoy as well, and they'd like more, not less, material. This is more likely to happen in non-required courses.

@PasserBy I hope that's the case. It's just one student told me "This hardest thing I have done in my academic life."

Hard isn't mutually exclusive with enjoyable. Enjoyable hardness is called "challenge".

What did the other 50% report? Less than 20h? More than 28h? Or did the other 50% not answer that question?

Do students actually answer these question truthfully?

If this is a 5 credit class, and I'm taking 20 credits (a load that was challenging, but doable at my university), and if the time spent on schoolwork is based on that 20-28 hours for 5 credits, that would be a 80-112 hour school week.  That seems like an enormous amount, to put it mildly.  You say this class should be about "half" of their normal workload...so the average student is only taking two classes for 10 credits at this point at this institution?  (That seems odd, so I'm just trying to verify I'm not missing something.)

@FedericoPoloni yes. Why not? If you were slow, you want them to know it is too hard. If you were fast, you want them to know the speed/difficulty is good.

@Beska The total number of credits does not matter for my question. It's about 40%-50% of total credits they are working for when they took my course.

@LeafGlowPath The total number of credits does matter.  In the US, the typical rule of thumb is that a student taking 12 credit hours is considered a full-time student (though most students are advised to take 15ish credit hours per semester).  "Full-time" means (roughly) 40 hours per week, and 12 credit hours is about 10 hours of class time per week, leaving another 30 hours of work outside of class.  So the expectation is that 1 credit hour corresponds to roughly 2.5 total hours of outside work, hence a 5 credit class would expect around 7.5 hours of work outside of class.

On the other hand, if 5 credits is half of a full load (hence 10 credits is a full load), and each credit corresponds to 50 minutes of in-class time (so 10 credits is a little more than 8 hours), then it would be fair to expect students to do about 32 hours of work outside of class, or a bit more than 3 hours per credit.  This is more than 15 hours of outside work per week for a 5 credit class.  So the total expected load is important in understanding load.

Ack... math error in the first comment:  5(2.5) = 12.5, not 7.5.

Your university should provide some guidance here. As an arbitrary example, UCLA states that "One unit represents three hours of work per week per term by the student, including both class attendance and preparation." It seems that Physics 1A is a 5 credit course, and it meets for four hours a week, so 5*3-4 = 11 hours/week of homework and studying. In this case yes, if the average student were spending 20 hours/week, you should consider lowering your expectations.
In your case, I'm not sure what "the university suggested 20 hours/week" might mean, and I'm not sure what "more that 20 hours/week" means (how much more?). You should probably clarify these points.
Finally, note that students are pretty bad at estimating how much time they spend studying. You should go through the course yourself and estimate how many hours each assignment, reading, and exam will require. You can then occasionally cross-check these estimates by asking the students how long they spent on a specific task. Even here, you want to ask the question in a very precise way: having them write down the time blocks that they devoted to the homework onto a piece of scratch paper, sum then, and report the total will be much more accurate than just asking them to estimate the total time.

One thing I have found helps is to ask students for time assessments in smaller increments. For example, I ask for every hand-in an (obviously ungraded) question "how much time in hours did you spend on this assignment (including reading, self-study, debugging, etc.)?". This is much easier to estimate for students than at the end oof the course how much time they spent on all things together.

As opposed to mit, which uses a system where most classes are either 9 or 12 credits, and those numbers roughly represent the total number of hours per week most students will spend on that class. How many hours are reasonable for any given student in any given term is something they and their advisors need to figure out, but this gives them a basis for making those assessments. Note that there are students who thrive on 60 hours of class and homework a week, and others who struggle at 40.

My experience is that students spend a lot of time on a course, but it’s rarely efficient time, i.e. there’s a lot of chatting/checking social media/searching youtube  but not a lot of actual working.

I applaud the OP for caring enough to try to improve their teaching. I have had the exact same experience. Our academic credit hour policy states that students are supposed to spend 12 hours per week on each course (with 4 courses, that's 48 hours). I used to get similar evaluations to the OP, so I started to survey the students during the semester. Around the middle of the semester, I give students a Google Form to ask how things are going, and call it a midsemester evaluation. I added a question asking how many hours per week students are working, and got wildly varying answers. Then I honed the question to instruct them to think about a specific week and count, and I got the expected normal distribution. It was indeed high, so I streamlined the course, cut a bit from the homework (removing any "busy work" style questions), and cut unnecessary sections.
I do midsemester evaluations every semester and keep the data on student hours. After midsemester evaluations, I show students the data and the credit hour policy. I also point out that a lot of students who report not doing well are working less than 12 hours a week. From doing this, I have learned that most courses on campus do not meet the credit hour policy, and assign less than 12 hours a week, making mine look like an outlier to the students. But when I show them the policy, this seems to help, and complaints drop. I invite students to seek extra help if they are putting in way too many hours, and I devote a day to time management. I do this because many students who report spending more than 12 hours a week will reveal, if I ask them, that they are often doing their math homework in bed, while watching a movie or texting with a friend, etc. The midsemester evaluation is a teachable moment, to teach them effective and efficient work/study habits.

What kind of questions do you ask other than the hours? I did try this before but what I usually got is "This is too hard!"

The simplest evaluation would be four questions: (1) What's going well for your learning? (2) What's not going well? (3) What can I (the professor) do differently? (4) What can you (the student) do differently?

Mine has those, but also some Likert scale questions about whether or not they like the book, read it before class, watch the videos, feel they can learn from the videos, feel they learn from the HW, feel the exams are fair, etc. Another option would be to use the language from the end of semester evaluations that the university administers.

You don't state what formula your university recommendation uses to come up with 20 hours a week for your course, but 20 hours per week for the average student seems super high to me (almost a factor of 2) for a course that is approximately 25% of a student's course load.
The NYS definition of a semester hour is  (from https://www.rochester.edu/provost/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/ur-credit-hour-policies-updated-march-2019-v.-for-posting.pdf) "Semester hour means a credit, point, or other unit granted for the satisfactory completion of a course which requires at least 15 hours (of 50 minutes each) of instruction and at least 30 hours of supplementary assignments, except as otherwise provided...."  We have to play some games to scale this to a 14-week semester, but however we do it, it comes out to way closer to 10 hours a week than 20 (I believe our "official" policy comes out to around 12 for a 4-credit course.
Let's look at it this way.  We'll start by assuming your course is about a 25% work load for a student — one course out of a "typical" 4 course load (even though that feels low to me).  That means that if we go by your 20 hour guideline, that the average student will be putting 80 hours per week into nothing but classes!  I rarely put in 80 hour weeks.  I'm sure it happened every now and again when I was a student, but it would have been pretty rare.  Not every student is average, and some will need to put more than the average time into a course than the average student.  Under the 20-hour guideline, these students may be putting in 90–100hrs/week.
My own rule of thumb for time expectations is that a work week should be about 40 hrs, and that four courses a semester works out to and average of about 10 hours/wk for each course, split between class time and everything else.  Some students will need more, and some can get away with less.

In a comment, the OP states that the course is half the workload, not a quarter. Not typical, of course.

OP didn't mention the country, but their description is definitively reasonable if applied to some European institutions using a quarter system with 15 ECTS credits/quarter and (some) courses with 7.5 credits.

Here you will find the European credit system (ECTS units): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Credit_Transfer_and_Accumulation_System
As you can see, there is some variance between countries how many working hours amounts to 1 ECTS (a whole year = 60 ECTS). You should consider the total workload for a student, not of you course in isolation. For example, I teach in Denmark where a semester (half a year) amounts to 30 ECTS. On my 10 ECTS course, I can demand 10*28=280 hours from a student (confer with the table in above link). The student might haven chosen 4 courses, for example, at 10+10+5+5 = 30 ECTS. Students might on occasion sign up for more or less than 30 ECTS, knowing exactly the workload to expect. Just multiply the ECTS by 28 hours/ECTS.

This.  I think that it is entirely reasonable to expect a full-time student to devote somewhere between 40 and 50 hours per week on their schooling.  Maybe even a bit more.  It is impossible to know how much work is reasonable on a per-class basis without knowing the expected load a student is taking on.
